# Using inv() function in Matlab crashes using all the RAM

Tags: matlab, matrix-inverse

I have a sparse matrix in Matlab 43916x43916, which is calculated by this equation:

```
B=(speye(nV,nV)-alpha*NeMatrix+beta*NeMatrix*NeMatrix);
```

being `nV`a int, `alpha`a int, `NeMatrix` a sparse matrix and `beta` a int.

I can't do inv(B) because it increases the use of RAM till it crashes. I've tried LU already with no success.

How can I alternatively calculate this inverse matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse will be a dense matrix. Thus you should check, whether you can handle a matrix of this size. Try, e.g., to set up `ones(nV,nV)` ...
If you have enough storage, you may consider to compute the inverse column wise. The i-th column would be `B\ei`, where `ei` is the i-th unit vector.

HOWEVER, in numerical computations you hardly ever need the inverse of a matrix `B`. Most times `B\v` is enough, where `v` is a vector. So you better check, whether you really need the full inverse...

Comment: I've replaced the inv(B). `Bx = C, x = B\C`. Thanks.